# Bitbucket - request approval only for specific files

Tags: bitbucket, rights

Is it possible with Bitbucket to request that a certain group approves the PR on a specific file?

please, let me know If I need to develop.

Thanks,

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: AzureDevops calls this "Automatic Reviewers". GitHub calls it "Codeowners". If you search for "bitbucket codeowners" you will find some plugins that can help with this.